# Neomake prints results to terminal when invoking upon wq

Tags: neovim, plugin-neomake

In my `.config/nvim/init.vim` I have

```
autocmd BufWritePost * Neomake
```

This works well when writing the file.  But when writing and quitting with `:wq`, the results are prented on the terminal:

```
[user:~] $ vi stackexchange.py

Neomake: flake8 complete with exit code 0
Neomake: pep8 complete with exit code 0[user:~] $
```

How can I quiet this output?

Comment: Did you do `:help neomake`?

Comment: I have looked it over in varying detail.  I didn't find anything related my issue. In fact, it's quite long and the vast majority of it has absolutely nothing to do with my problem.

Comment: Maybe `silent! Neomake`?

Comment: @muru unfortunately `silent!` doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an open issue: [Do not run makers on `:wq`](https://github.com/benekastah/neomake/issues/309)

The workaround mentioned in that issue:

```
autocmd! QuitPre * let g:neomake_verbose = 0
```